# Unable to add Job Listener in Sundial Job Scheduler

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

I am trying to add JobListener in Sundial Job Scheduler similiar to below in quartz

```
scheduler.getListenerManager().addJobListener(myJobListener,    or(jobGroupEquals("myJobGroup"), jobGroupEquals("yourGroup")));
```

but there is no addJobListener in ListenerManager which I got using below code

```
SundialJobScheduler.getScheduler().getListenerManager()
```

Here am I missing anything or it is not possible in sundial Scheduler.

Also Is there anyway to add jobgroup in sundial job scheduler?

Thanks,